# Can't use QtQuick (QML) on Qt 5.7.1

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick, qt5.7

I use Qt 5.7.1 and Qt Creator 4.2.0 and I tried to use QtQuick.
**But I can't compile any QtQuick project.**

Even when I try to just create a basic QtQuick Application and then compile it (*without any modification*), I have the following error:

> qrc:/main.qml:1 plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick": Failed to extract plugin meta data from 'C:/Qt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick.2/qtquick2plugind.dll'

I checked and the dll exists. I also tried to compile in release mod.
I also tried to run a Qt example (planet-qml) but I have the same error message.

Strange thing is that **it works on 5.5.0 Qt** version.

Does anyone have any idea of why this is not working?
Thanks for your help and have a good day!

Comment: Try reinstall Qt.

Comment: I did, and it stills not work.

Comment: And what is it now? :)